# Opening onclick events python requests library

Tags: javascript, python, onclick, python-requests, screen-scraping

Tried to get links to all issues of a publication for a given year, from this link: http://www.vetsci.org/journal/list.html?pn=vol&year=2018. 
E.g: "Jan. Vol. 19 No.1. 1~160", which has an 'onclick' event.

*edited*

I would appreciate any help with how to do the following:

- first, activate the onclick event;
- second, get the link of the page to which the onclick event is leading the browser -> I have used the developer tools after clicking, to see the link of the new page. However, since this is no different to manually clicking and copy/pasting the url, I would like to know if there is a way to automatically read these links.

*edited*

Hope I am not spamming, since there are a couple of other threads on issues with getting popups and similar, but those seem like somewhat advanced stuff - at least from where I am standing :)

Comment: You'd need to use something like selenium webdriver for that

Answer (score 1):

If you want to activate the event itself in any situation, you'll need something like Selenium. If you want to retrieve the page in the example you gave, inspection of the code shows that the onClick event loads the `list.html` page with parameters like so:

`http://www.vetsci.org/journal/list.html?s_v={volume}&s_n={number}&sort=start_Page*1&TG=&pn=vol&year=2018&sm={4th argument}`

I can't quite tell what the 4th argument is supposed to be because it's blank in all the examples you gave. If you do a `GET` request on that URL, you can use something like BeautifulSoup to parse the page.